# El efecto wave no se adapta en dispositivos pequeños

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema, una de las secciones de mi página posee un efecto wave en la parte de abajo de la misma. Todo se ve bien en dispositivos grandes, pero en dispositivos mas pequeños, la wave se sube y queda un pedazo de otro color, por lo que yo creo que no esta pudiendose adaptar aquellos dispositivos, alguna solución? Otra cosa extraña que pasa es que en la consola del navegador se puede ver bien si elijo el tamaño del dispositivo, pero si lo veo desde un dispositivo real no ocurre. Para que se den una idea dejo una imagen de lo que me esta ocurriendo, ya que creo que no se puede apreciar al ejecutar el código.

[image: La parte celeste es la wave y como se aprecia en la img, está mas arriba que el final de la sección, que a su vez comienza la otra sección con el mismo color de fondo (celeste) que la wave. Lo que debería pasar en la img es que la wave celeste este al final de la primera sección dandole un efecto de llenado o rebalsado.]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/** SECCION "INICIO"*/

#inicio {
    background-color: #1D1C1C;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

#inicio .wave {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

#inicio .contenido header {
    background-color: rgba(22,193,185, .8);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    min-height:  30px;
    max-height: 70px;
}

#inicio .contenido header .contenido-header {
    max-width: 1100px ;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px ;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.checkbtn {
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    height: 70vh;
    top: 69px;
    right: -100%;
    background-color: #2A2929;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 1s; 
}

.menu-visible {
    right: 0;
}

#inicio .contenido header .contenido-header nav ul li {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 50px 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#inicio .contenido header .contenido-header nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#inicio .contenido header .contenido-header nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #F99831;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#inicio .contenido header .contenido-header nav ul li a::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #F99831;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: calc(100% + 10px);
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

#inicio .contenido header .contenido-header nav ul li a:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}

header.abajo {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #fff; 
}

#inicio .contenido .presentacion {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

#inicio .contenido .presentacion h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.tit-present {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.carl {
    border: 3px solid #16C1B9;
    padding: 0;
}

#name-color {
    color: #F99831;
    font-style: italic;
}

.soy {
    color: #16C1B9;
    font-style: italic;
}

#check {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="inicio">

        <div class="contenedor-inicio">

        <div class="wave" style="height: 150px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0.8;" ><svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" 
        preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <path d="M0.00,49.98 C141.36,-36.00 372.74,205.77 500.00,49.98 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z" 
        style="stroke: none; fill: #C87115;"></path></svg></div>

        <div class="wave" style="height: 150px; overflow: hidden;" ><svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" 
        preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <path d="M0.00,49.98 C149.99,150.00 349.20,-49.98 500.00,49.98 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z" 
        style="stroke: none; fill: #16C1B9;"></path></svg></div>

        <div class="contenido">

            <header>

                <div class="contenido-header">   

                    <h1><span>CJ</span></h1>

                        <!--Icono del menu responsive -->
                    
                         <input type="checkbox" id="check">

                            <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
                            </label>

                            <nav class="nav-menu  menu">

                                <ul id="links">
                                    <li><a href="#inicio"><b>INICIO</b></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#datospersonales"><b>DATOS PERSONALES</b></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#formacionacademica"><b>FORMACION ACADÉMICA</b></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#experiencia"><b>EXPERIENCIA</b></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#habilidades"><b>HABILIDADES</b></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#contacto"><b>CONTACTO</b></a></li>
                                </ul>

                            </nav>

                </div>

            </header>

            <div class="presentacion">

                <h2 class="tit-present">Hola! Mi nombre es <span id="name-color">Carl Johnson</span>, 
                <br> soy profesor de <span class="typed"></span></h2>

                <img src="CARL - copia.png" alt="Retrato de Carl Johnson" class="carl">
            
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
        
    </section>
```

Comment: Buen día, estoy reproduciendo tu código en todas las resoluciones ([aquí por ejemplo](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/Jjadwar)) y no veo que el problema que mencionas esté ocurriendo. En qué momento te sucede ese problema? tienes algún código adicional?

Comment: Buen día @Cris223511.dev, la imagen que compartí es una captura de pantalla  mi celular,  en el cual esa wave no se logra adaptar a ese dispositivo. Además, probé en demás dispositivos pequeños y ocurre lo mismo. Como mencioné antes, en la consola de mi navegador tampoco se puede apreciar ese error, por lo que no logro comprender que es lo que me debe estar dando problemas o que me debe estar faltando algo